# Changing TYPO3 backend powermail tools

Tags: typo3, powermail

I want to change the TYPO3 backend tool layout of powermail, about the template Resources\Private\Partials\Module\ListOld.html and for the exports (xls,csv). 
The change of that template should happen within a new extension. It seems that it is not enough, to change the partials setup, within the TypoScript config like this:

```
plugin.tx_powermail {
    view {
        partialRootPaths.30 = EXT:ext_name/Resources/Private/Partials/
    }
}
```

Powermail: 2.25.2
TYPO3: 6.2.19

What did I forget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the TypoScript for backend modules should be done with `module.tx_extkey...`